Error: (0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.createContext) is not a function
I'm new to next.js and I'm facing this error from past two days but can't find any way to debug it:
Error: (0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.createContext) is not a function

after deep research, i can say that it is MAYBE due to some dependency issues. This is my package.json:
"dependencies": {
    "@toruslabs/eccrypto": "^5.0.1",
    "@walletconnect/ethereum-provider": "2.13.3",
    "@web3auth/web3auth": "2.1.3",
    "bn.js": "^5.2.1",
    "ethers": "5.7.0",
    "magic-sdk": "^28.0.7",
    "moralis": "^2.26.7",
    "moralis-v1": "^1.13.0",
    "next": "14.2.4",
    "pino-pretty": "^11.2.1",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-moralis": "^1.4.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "yarn-deduplicate": "^6.0.2"
}

and error remains even after using 'use client'
please help me
I hope that you guys help me its too frustrating for me as a next.js begninner

share your webpack config
